# On saving CSV file into server directory, all values save only in first column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I'm trying to create csv and saving the file on server, later which will be send as attachment, following is the code to create & save file on server,

```
    $fileref=$records['referencenum']; //Dynamically generated
    $filename = "$fileref.csv";
    $outputfile = fopen('$filename', 'w');  
    $output = array('Record Type 1',
        'Record Type 2',
        'Record Type 3',
        'Record Type 4',
        'Record Type 5',
        'Record Type 6'
    );          
    file_put_contents("attachments/" . $filename, $output);
    fclose($outputfile);
```

Above code can create and save file on server but the problem is that it saves all records in first column of csv file.

What I'm doing wrong and what will be the solution to fix the problem?

Regards

**Edited & Solution**

```
    $fileref=$records['referencenum']; //Dynamically generated
    $filename = "$fileref.csv";
    $output = fopen("attachments/" . $filename, "w");   //should have folder path
   //Arrays should be load in same variable as fopen();
    fputcsv($output, array(RecordType1,
        RecordType2,
        RecordType3,
        RecordType4,
        RecordType5,
        RecordType6
      )//No spaces and No comma
    );
    fputcsv($output);
    fclose($output); //close the file
    file_put_contents("attachments/" . $filename); //no need of this
```

No need of foreach, as only saving values in single row.
and it worked.
Thanks to **Ankii Gangrade** who suggested to try fputcsv();

Comment: “`file_put_contents("attachments/" . $filename); //no need of $output varibale here`” – no need of `file_put_contents` _at all_ there; by using `fopen`/`fputcsv`/`fclose` you have switched out the “method” of writing to the file for a totally different one . Remove `file_put_contents` completely, it does not make sense in this context at all.

Comment: you were right, “file_put_contents("attachments/" . $filename); //no need of $output varibale here”-- no need of it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fputcsv()

```
<?php
$fileref=$records['referencenum']; //Dynamically generated
$filename = "$fileref.csv";
$list = array (
    array('xyz', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('$filename', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```